# Which Windows flavors have a UI for editing a file's DACL?

Tags: windows, security

I noticed that some flavors of Windows (XP Home, etc ...) doesn't allow the user to edit a file's DACL. I'm wondering if there is a list or something somewhere that states which flavors have it and which don't. If there is not list, let's figure this out right here on this.

Comment: Does `cacls` count as a UI? What about if "Security" tab only appears in Safe Mode? What if you have enable it manually (XP Pro)?

Comment: It doesn't matter. I'm basically trying to figure out when and how I can modify the DACL using a UI (not programmatically). A CACL doesn't count.

Comment: DACL = Discretionary Access Control List, for all those who didn't know.  ( I had to look it up ).